# Create database programatically from PHP on WHM/cPanel server

Tags: php, database, cpanel, whm

I was wondering whether it is possible to create a new database and user, from PHP, on an WHM/cPanel server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is the thing.

'mysql_create_db' function does not work properly on cPanel servers.

There is a solution to this though, by using the proprietary cPanel function like so

`http://USER:PASS@HOST:2082/frontend/SKIN/sql/adddb.html?db=DB`

There is also a ready-made script that can be used here http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-database-creator.php

Comment: no error while having like- http://USER:PASS@HOST:2082/frontend/SKIN/sql/adddb.html?db=DB but also no database created; is there otherway

Answer (score 2):

For CPanel:

```
function create_db($cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$dbName) {

$buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/sql/addb.html?db=".$dbName;

$openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
if(!$openSocket) {
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
}

$authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
$authPass = base64_encode($authString);
$buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
}
fclose($openSocket);


//echo "Created database $dbName";

}

create_db('username','password','dbName');
```

Answer (score 0):

**To create a DB:**

```
mysql_query('create database foo');
```

or

```
mysql_create_db('foo');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php

**To create a MySQL user:**

You can create user account by generating the SQL and running it through `mysql_query` (just like the first example): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I dont think this is possible. cPanel does not simply allow you to create databases like that using any cPanel user ID/pwd. You need to use the root credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user you use to connect to the database has the appropriate privileges defined in MySQL this shouldn't be a problem.

To create databases the user needs the [CREATE privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) (to drop them that would be DROP privilege), to create user(s) you need to have the [CREATE USER privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user). You also might need the [GRANT OPTION privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option) to be able to grant privileges to other users.

So as long as the DB user(s) you can create through WHM/cPanel have these privileges, you should be ok.